# throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors ^ TypeError: rows.forEach is not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express

I am new to Node js and trying to start learning it by coding rest api in node js,

I am trying to add data to my mysql phpmyadmin database using this code, and wanna print result what data was added

```
app.post('/employees', (req, res) => {
    var emp = req.body;
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `employee` SET ?";
    mysqlConnection.query(sql, emp , (err, rows, fields) => { 
        if (!err){
            rows.forEach(element => {
                if(element.constructor == Array)
                res.send('Inserted employee id : '+element[0].EmpID);
                res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
             });
        }
        else
            console.log(err);
    })
});
```

data is getting added to the database but node js connection is shutting down and I am getting this error

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: rows.forEach is not a function
```

Comment: Did you check the value of rows? It seems it is non-array property.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara how do I check?

Answer (score 0):

This error message suggests that you are trying to call the forEach method on an object in JavaScript that does not have this method defined.

The most common reason for this error is that the object you are trying to iterate over with `forEach` is not an array. The `forEach` method is only defined on array objects in JavaScript.

To fix this error, you can check if the object is an array before using `forEach`. You can do this by using the `Array.isArray()` method, which returns `true` if the object is an array, and `false` otherwise.

**For example:**

```js
if (Array.isArray(js)) 
{
  js.forEach(function(item) 
  {
    // Do something with each item in the array
  });
} 
else 
{
  // Handle the case where js is not an array
}
```